# Iframe in Materialize Carousel Not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, carousel, materialize

In Materialize Carousel method instead of normal images, I have inserted Iframe to embed a web link in slides. On inserting Iframes, clicking to switch slide doesn't work.

Carousel Method:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item"> <iframe style=' max-height: 700px; max-width: 420px; width: 340px; height: 566px;' src='http://www.website.com' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen scrolling='no'></iframe></a>
    <a class="carousel-item"> <iframe style=' max-height: 700px; max-width: 420px; width: 340px; height: 566px;' src='http://www.website.com' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen scrolling='no'></iframe></a>
    <a class="carousel-item"> <iframe style=' max-height: 700px; max-width: 420px; width: 340px; height: 566px;' src='http://www.website.com' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen scrolling='no'></iframe></a>
    <a class="carousel-item"> <iframe style=' max-height: 700px; max-width: 420px; width: 340px; height: 566px;' src='http://www.website.com' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen scrolling='no'></iframe></a>
</div>
```

The non active slides are not clickable. On clicking, they don't get activated.
Kindly help me find a solution

Answer (score 2):

In the iframe's `style` attribute, add:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to disable click events on the iframe. This will make sure click events correctly bubble up to the Materialize Carousel plugin.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for moving from one carousel item to another. But I'm not able do operations on the active carousel item. Every Iframe I have has hover and click events. Any way to make that work in this?